# grails how to debug sitemesh inclusion

Tags: grails

I've got the line:

```
  static layout = "loggedIn"
```

in one controller, and the loggedIn.gsp layout is used for views in this controller.   I included the same line in another controller, but it doesn't include this layout, rather using main.gsp in the layouts folder.   Any thoughts on how I can resolve this / figure out what is going on?   Note loggedIn.gsp is in the layouts folder, it is just ignored by the second controller for some reason, which includes the exact same

```
  static layout = "loggedIn"
```

line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that the view has a meta.layout property in it.

Layouts get triggered in this order of precedence:

- meta.layout `<meta name="layout" content="main"/>`
- static 'layout' property on the controller
- controller/action conventions:

  - /layouts/${controller}/${action}.gsp
  - /layouts/${controller}.gsp
- configured `grails.sitemesh.default.layout` property
- /layouts/application.gsp

http://www.slideshare.net/laelfrog/grails-layouts-sitemesh (slide 19)

Comment: Thanks for providing this precedence.   I'll look forward to reviewing your presentation.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a remnant:

```
  <meta name="layout" content="main" />
```

in pages for the second controller, which overrides the static layout setting inside the controller.